# 70's Peugeot to Fixed Gear Conversion

Tags: wheels, fixed-gear, conversion, dropouts, peugeot

I have an old 1970's Peugeot frame (originally a 10-speed, I believe) that I have been slowly trying to convert to a fixed gear bike. I am at a complete loss for which wheelset is appropriate. I have a rudimentary wooden ruler that says the rear dropouts are 122mm, which doesn't sound right. From what I understand, it should be the standard 120mm... The frame has no dents and doesn't appear to be bent, at least to the naked eye. The front dropouts are 97mm.

Can I feel comfortable ordering a 700c wheelset with 120mm frame spacing?

Comment: You do realize that pretty much any frame made will flex by 2mm between the rear dropouts, and that there is often that much variation in the width of hubs, depending on how tight the bearings are, et al.

Comment: Lot's of useful advice for old steel bikes on this page. https://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use 120mm hub. In my opinion the frame is well within tolerance for 70s steel bike. If the difference bothers you, you can add an 1mm spacer to each side between cone and locknut.